# insert a num into list

Tags: python, insert

Trying to insert v into a list just before the rightmost item greater than v, or at index 0 if no items are greater than v.

```
def insert(lst,v)

>>> my_list = [3, 10, 4, 2]
>>> insert(my_list, 5)
>>> my_list
[3, 5, 10, 4, 2]

>>> my_list = [4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> insert(my_list, 20)
>>> my_list
[20, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Where is `insert` defined?

Comment: it's "def insert(lst, v)"     trying to insert v into lst

Comment: Please edit your original post to include any new information. Code formatting is lost in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert(L, v):
    for i in range(len(L)-1, -1, -1):
        if L[i] > v:
            L.insert(i, v)
            return L
    L.insert(0, v)
    return L
```

Comment: `insert([3, 10, 4, 2], 5) => [5, 3, 10, 4, 2]`, you should probably just insert at `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=len(lst)-1
while i>0 and lst[i]<v:
    i=i-1
lst.insert(i,v)
```

Comment: @inspectorG4dget's solution is more pythonic in my opinion. Why don't you just accept that one? Not that there's anything wrong with posting an answer to your own question. But for potential future readers, it's nice to add a short explanation in an answer, in addition to the source code.